# How to combine these commands to SSH into remote machine?

Tags: command-line, ssh, vpn, remote-access, ssh-tunnel

I have three machines, let's call them **Work**, **Home** and **Laptop**, all on different networks. My goal is to remotely SSH into **Home** from **Laptop**. This is how I do this currently:

1. Connect all three machines to the same university VPN.
2. Run this command on **Home**: `ssh -R 19999:localhost:22 <work_ip>` .
3. Run this command on **Laptop**: `ssh <work_username>@<work_ip>`.
4. Run this command on **Laptop** (which is now remotely connected to **Work**): `ssh <home_username>@localhost -p 19999`.

At the end of step 4, I'm now remotely connected to **Home** from **Laptop**.

Is there a one-line SSH command that simplifies these steps, so that I can use it for example in VS Code to connect from **Laptop** to **Home**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 & 2** should be considered a separate task, since you can just leave Home connected to Work (and probably can't run remote commands if it's not connected, right?). Maybe use [autossh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh) or add a scheduled job to attempt to reconnect the vpn/ssh if disconnected?

**3 & 4** can just be combined into one line using the syntax `ssh user@host [command]`. You may need to specify `-t` to get a working terminal, especially if step 4 requires an interactive step like a password:

```
[user@Laptop ~]$ ssh -t work_user@work_ip ssh home_user@localhost -p 19999
```

Forwarding with `-J` is usually cleaner (less listening sockets), but not when you're setting up the reverse tunnel already. It also requires forwarding to be enabled on the work host:

```
[user@Laptop ~]$ ssh -J work_user@work_ip home_user@localhost -p 19999
```